# Java FX BarChart not working as desired

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart based that shows the values based on the given criteria. Somehow the chart is not behaving as I expected. Depending on how many times I click, it keeps on adding to the number of bars. Please take a look at the image below. There is a button event that generates this graph and the bars are increasing by the number of times I click the button. [image]

```
package com.naveen;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class AppController {

    @FXML
    Label total_energy_result, downstream_energy_result, upstream_energy_result, error;
    @FXML
    TextField temperature;
    @FXML
    TextField moisture;
    @FXML
    TextField natural_gas;
    @FXML
    TextField diesel;
    @FXML
    TextField light_fuel_gas;
    @FXML
    TextField lpg;

    @FXML
    PieChart chart;

    @FXML
    NumberAxis yAxis;

    @FXML
    CategoryAxis xAxis;

    @FXML
    BarChart<String, Double> bar_chart;

    @FXML
    Button calculate_total_energy, generate_chart;

    private double downstream_energy;
    private double natural_gas_percent;
    private double diesel_percent;
    private double light_fuel_gas_percent;
    private double lpg_percent;
    private double upstream_energy;
    private double total_energy;

    public void doStuff(ActionEvent e) {

        calculate_total_energy.setOnAction(event -> {
            downstream_energy = (26352.77 * Double.parseDouble(moisture.getText()))
                    + (537.98 * Double.parseDouble(temperature.getText())) - 32598.9;
            natural_gas_percent = (Double.parseDouble(natural_gas.getText()) * 0.111868434193638) / 100;
            diesel_percent = (Double.parseDouble(diesel.getText()) * 0.16015875221474) / 100;
            light_fuel_gas_percent = (Double.parseDouble(light_fuel_gas.getText()) * 0.155217414842077) / 100;
            lpg_percent = (Double.parseDouble(lpg.getText()) * 0.0890627449471606) / 100;

            upstream_energy = downstream_energy
                    * (natural_gas_percent + diesel_percent + light_fuel_gas_percent + lpg_percent);

            total_energy = downstream_energy + upstream_energy;

            total_energy_result.setText(Math.round(total_energy) + " BTU");
            downstream_energy_result.setText(Math.round(downstream_energy) + " BTU");
            upstream_energy_result.setText(Math.round(upstream_energy) + " BTU");

            chart.setData(getData());
            chart.setClockwise(false);
            chart.setLegendSide(Side.BOTTOM);
            chart.setLabelsVisible(true);
            chart.setLabelLineLength(10);

            xAxis.setLabel("Fuel Type");
            yAxis.setLabel("%");

            XYChart.Series<String, Double> series1 = new Series<String, Double>();
            XYChart.Series<String, Double> series2 = new Series<String, Double>();
            XYChart.Series<String, Double> series3 = new Series<String, Double>();
            XYChart.Series<String, Double> series4 = new Series<String, Double>();

            series1.getData()
                    .add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("Natural", Double.parseDouble(natural_gas.getText())));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("Diesel", Double.parseDouble(diesel.getText())));
            series3.getData()
                    .add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("Light Fuel", Double.parseDouble(light_fuel_gas.getText())));
            series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("LPG", Double.parseDouble(lpg.getText())));
            bar_chart.getData().addAll(series1,series2,series3,series4);

        });
    }

    private ObservableList<Data> getData() {
        ObservableList<Data> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        observableList.addAll(new PieChart.Data("DownStream", downstream_energy),
                new PieChart.Data("UpStream", upstream_energy));
        return observableList;
    }

}
```

Comment: You appear to be setting an action listener *inside* an action listener.... (depending on what's in your FXML file). And then inside that action listener you add four new series to the existing series in the bar chart. Maybe it would help if you explained what you were actually trying to do, since this would appear to be the expected behavior.

Comment: I removed that ActionEvent from the method signature. Now, the idea is to display the fuel types on the xAxis and its values on the yAxis. I have four categories of Fuel Types. Please let me know how to do them.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference if you remove the parameter. It's still an action handler method, no? Not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like I said, idea is to display fuel types on xAxis and values on yAxis. I have four types of fuel types and I added them to the series but somehow its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to correct the code.

```
    XYChart.Series<String, Double> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<String, Double> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<String, Double> series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<String, Double> series4 = new XYChart.Series<>();

            xAxis.setLabel("Fuel Type");
            yAxis.setLabel("%");

            series1.getData()
                    .add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("Natural", Double.parseDouble(natural_gas.getText())));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("Diesel", Double.parseDouble(diesel.getText())));
            series3.getData()
                    .add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("Light Fuel", Double.parseDouble(light_fuel_gas.getText())));
            series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Double>("LPG", Double.parseDouble(lpg.getText())));

            bar_chart.getData().add(series1);
            bar_chart.getData().add(series2);
            bar_chart.getData().add(series3);
            bar_chart.getData().add(series4);

            bar_chart.setLegendVisible(false);
```